# Magento Grand Total Calculates Total without adding shipping Tax

Tags: magento, invoice

So I have this weird thing going on in a magento 1.7.0.2 site I'm working on.

I've set up the shipping table rate and I've checked and re-checked all the Tax setting but I'm still getting two different sets of results from the same order.

The PDF invoice and the backend view of an invoice displays the correct totals including all the shipping costs and the tax. See below.

Screen Shot - http://biteandbang.com/stackOverImages/JM_Magento.jpg

However when viewing the products in the admin create order page the Shipping Tax is not included in the Grand Total. See image above.

Also the frontend of the site is not calculating the Tax on Shipping either. See below.

Screen Shot - http://biteandbang.com/stackOverImages/JM_FrontEnd.png

If anyone has any suggestions I'd appreciate it. This one has me confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody changed the value in `System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Tax Classes` in the `Tax Class for Shipping` drop down.

Take a look on this value and then go to `Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules` and filter by the correct `Customer Tax Class` and in `Product Tax Class` choose the value that you looked before.

Now go through the filtered `Tax Rules` and check out whether the applied `Tax Rates` are correct.